# How do i write the condition in sql to get the required result SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables (1) Updates (2) Companies

Updates Table Columns: ID, Title, inserted_at, updated_at, revisions, published_at, archived_at, versions

Companies Table columns: id, name, host, email, inserted_at, updated_at, features.

How do I write a query to show how many posts have been made by a company.

What I know so far is I need to use COUNT in the query but how can I get the no. of updates by a company using that?

```
SELECT COUNT (column_name)
FROM TABLE (table_name)
condition??
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Please define how you count the updates.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add a column "company_id" in Updates table which will reference the ID column in Companies table. You will need to add this column then only you can identify which update was made by which company.

So the new structure will be as follows

```
Companies (ID, name, host, email, inserted_at, updated_at, features)<br/>
Updates (ID, title, inserted_at, updated_at, revisions, published_at, archived_at, company_id)
```

Then use the following command to select the count of updates

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM updates WHERE company_id = 1;
```

Or if you want for all the companies then use the following command

```
SELECT u.company_id, c.name COUNT(u.company_id) FROM companies c, updates u, WHERE c.id =  u.company_id GROUP BY u.company_id, c.name;
```